# Pandas | read_csv | to_xml | ValueError: Invalid tag name 'foo bar'

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, csv

Hi my fellow freinds from Stack Overflow,

I want to use python to ***convert csv to xml*** and it came to my ears that **pandas** could be very simple to manage this task.

Well it turns out its not so eazy.

***What my code looks like:***

```
import pandas as pd
import chardet
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

csvFile = '172431-82056.csv'
xmlFile = 'mySecondData.xml'  

def check_encoding(filename):
    """
    input: filename = "filename.csv"
    output: Dictionary = {'encoding': 'UTF-16', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
    """
    result= {}
    with open(filename, 'rb') as rawdata:
        result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(10000))
    return result

def import_csv(filename):
    """
    input: filename = "filename.csv"
    output: Dictionary = {'csv key': 'csv data', ... }
    """
    encoding = check_encoding(filename)['encoding']
    csv_data = pd.read_csv(filename, engine ='python', encoding=encoding, sep = None)
    #print(csv_data)
    return csv_data

#print(import_csv(csvFile))

def convert_to_xml(input_file, output_file):
    csv_data = import_csv(input_file)
    csv_data.to_xml(path_or_buffer=output_file, index = True, root_name='products',row_name='item', elem_cols=['post_title','regular_price'], prefix = 'g:', pretty_print=True)

convert_to_xml(csvFile, xmlFile)
```

***What my output looks like:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PavelH\Documents\Git\CSV Converter\csv_converter.py", line 53, in <module>
    convert_to_xml(csvFile, xmlFile)
  File "c:\Users\PavelH\Documents\Git\CSV Converter\csv_converter.py", line 51, in convert_to_xml
    df.to_xml(path_or_buffer=output_file, index = True, root_name='products',row_name='item', prefix = 'g:', pretty_print=True)
  File "C:\Users\PavelH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2986, in to_xml
    return xml_formatter.write_output()
  File "C:\Users\PavelH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\xml.py", line 265, in write_output
    xml_doc = self.build_tree()
  File "C:\Users\PavelH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\xml.py", line 485, in build_tree
    self.build_elems()
  File "C:\Users\PavelH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\xml.py", line 575, in build_elems
    SubElement(self.elem_row, elem_name).text = val
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3136, in lxml.etree.SubElement
  File "src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi", line 179, in lxml.etree._makeSubElement
  File "src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi", line 1734, in lxml.etree._tagValidOrRaise
ValueError: Invalid tag name 'foo bar'
```

Are tags with space invalid?

Comment: How does the csv look like? How should the xml look like? Add code snippets to the post.

Comment: Yes, XML node names cannot have spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command `pip install --upgrade pandas` solved this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't put questions in answers. If you have a new question, please open a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your pandas is outdated. `to_xml` has been introduced in version 1.3.0.
You can check your version with

```py
# in python shell
import pandas
print(pandas.__version__)
```

If this is an older version than 1.3.0, you should upgrade pandas with

```sh
# in bash shell
pip install --upgrade pandas
```