# Error converting pandas dataframe to xml saying Invalid Tag Name

Tags: python, pandas, xml, parsing

I have dataframe like:

```
Loader      TXN Description    ANUMS    Value Date
67805499    ZZ-OPTR            11504    1/27/2023 23:59
67805499    ZZ-OPTR            33002    1/27/2023 23:59
67805499    ZZ-OPTR            11504    1/27/2023 23:59
67805499    ZZ-OPTR            33002    1/27/2023 23:59
67805501    ZZ-OPTR            11504    1/27/2023 23:59
67805501    ZZ-OPTR            33002    1/27/2023 23:59
67805501    ZZ-OPTR            66666    1/27/2023 23:59
```

I want to convert this dataframe to xml and I used the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ShDalal\\Desktop\\twosigma.csv')
with open('outputf.xml', 'w') as myfile: 
  myfile.write(df.to_xml())
```

But it throws error saying:

```
ValueError: Invalid tag name 'Loader TXN ID'
```

What can be the reason for it

Comment: Welcome to SO. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: @Sheldon Is this error because of pandas version?

Comment: Possibly. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69569749/pandas-read-csv-to-xml-valueerror-invalid-tag-name-foo-bar

Comment: It looks like your problem is related to the space in the second column name. I would try renaming column `TXN Description` to `TXN_Description` and check whether you are still running into the same error.

Comment: @Sheldon I upgraded pandas but its still throwing same error.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the column as suggested in my latest comment?

Answer (score 2):

why this file open. Try this one to write the file:

```
df.to_xml('/path/to/file.xml')
```